# How to keep these two elements next to eachother

Tags: html, css, forms, input, send

So earlier I was coding my websites contact form, and I wanted to make it so I had to options, to go back or send. But I noticed that they weren't together. Now, I know that this is probably a very dumb question but I just got back from vacation so I have a huge brain fart. I would love all the help I could get.

Here is my HTML:

```
<p>Go Back <sup>or</sup></p><input type="submit" value="Send!" name="submit" />
```

I wish I could show an image but I can't at the moment.

Comment: You can make the "go back" and "send" hyperlink, this can ease out your work.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, put the `input` inside your `p` and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to the `<p>` tag:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jUS7Y/1/

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Try to use a class or id on it tho, or else all `<p>`-tags will turn into `inline-block`s.

**HTML**

```
<p class="myDescription">Go Back <sup>or</sup></p>
<input type="submit" value="Send!" name="submit" />
```

**CSS**

```
.myDescription {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Or just insert `input` inside `p`. Or change `p` to inline element (i.e. `span`).

Comment: @nd_macias agreed :) This answer was to take the OP's question very literally ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `<p></p>` tags act like a break to segment content in an HTML document. Include the Submit button inside the paragraph to avoid the break.

```
<p>Go Back <sup>or</sup> <input type="submit" value="Send!" name="submit" /></p>
```

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. Simply put; the `<p>` tag is a block-style, meaning it will wrap content under it, unless you use techniques like `float`. By changing the `<p>`-tag to `inline-block` it will get the property of an inline tag (like `<span>`) and will allow to have other content around it, without breaking the space.